# Changing bootstrap's datepicker position and behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker input field on my site, but it behaves weird and I couldn't figure out how to alter this behaviour.
First, when i click on the date field the datepicker box opens, but it looks like it opened from the field that is one up to my actualy date field.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

My other problem is when I choose a date. When I do this, I actually have to click somewhere outside the calendar box in order for it to close. Otherwise it wouldn't.
Any tips on how to fix issues will be appreciated. I am very new to this.

Here is my html(bs) :

```
<div id="lblNewApp" class="menu-content">

                <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Full Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="nameFull" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phoneApp" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailApp" readonly="readonly" >
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date" ">Date:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <!-- <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/> -->
              <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And jQuery :

```
 var date = new Date();
     $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
          maxDate: '+1m',              
          minDate: date,               
          daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]   
});
```

Comment: What's your screen size? Might be the issue of the screen size being too small?

Comment: I work on a 22'' monitor, so I don't believe it's the screen size.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: just a guess: What if you make the col-sm-2 containing the datepicker a position:relative? Could be the datepicker uses position absolute.. If that doesn't work, could you edit the question and add some of your custom CSS that touches the form fields (if any)?

Comment: nope, didn't work. thanks, though :)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have similar issues